# How can I restructure a JSON/Elasticsearch response

Tags: go

I'm using Olivere v7.

I'm trying to Merge `_id` & `_source` (from the ElasticSearch call, which returns a JSON response) into a re-ordered struct, and deliver results in that format.

This is what my actual code is:

```
elasticsearch, err := //actual request to ES using olivere
fmt.Println(elasticsearch.Hits.Hits)
```

and it successfully makes a call and prints this:

```
{
  "_score": 11.019884,
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "20",
  "_seq_no": null,
  "_primary_term": null,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Michael J.",
    "age": "22"
  }
},
{
  "_score": 11.019884,
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "21",
  "_seq_no": null,
  "_primary_term": null,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Michael Jae.",
    "age": "18"
  }
},
{
  "_score": 11.019884,
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "52",
  "_seq_no": null,
  "_primary_term": null,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Michael Jay.",
    "age": "69"
  }
},
{
  "_score": 11.019884,
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "33",
  "_seq_no": null,
  "_primary_term": null,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Michael Jo.",
    "age": "25"
  }
}
```

Instead, i would like to only print `"_id", "name", "age"`

So the desired output based on the same query above would be:

```
{
    "id": "20",
    "name": "Michael J.",
    "age": "22"
},
{
    "id": "21",
    "name": "Michael Jae.",
    "age": "18"
},
{
    "id": "52",
    "name": "Michael Jay.",
    "age": "69"
},
{
    "id": "33",
    "name": "Michael Jo.",
    "age": "25"
}
```

I've written this code:

```
elasticsearch, err := //actual request to ES using olivere

type StructuredResponse struct {
    ID             string  `json:"id"`
    Email          string `json:"email"`
    Name           string `json:"name"`
}

var SR []StructuredResponse
for _, hit := range elasticsearch.Hits.Hits {
    source, err := json.Marshal(hit.Source)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }


    var SR2 StructuredResponse
    err = json.Unmarshal(source, &SR2)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    SR = append(SR, SR2)
}

fmt.Println(SR)
```

But i'm lost, im not sure what the next step would be or what to do from here.

Update:

`elasticsearch.Hits.Hits` points to this struct within Olivere's package:

```
// SearchHit is a single hit.
type SearchHit struct {
    Score          *float64                       `json:"_score,omitempty"`   // computed score
    Index          string                         `json:"_index,omitempty"`   // index name
    Type           string                         `json:"_type,omitempty"`    // type meta field
    Id             string                         `json:"_id,omitempty"`      // external or internal
    Uid            string                         `json:"_uid,omitempty"`     // uid meta field (see MapperService.java for all meta fields)
    Routing        string                         `json:"_routing,omitempty"` // routing meta field
    Parent         string                         `json:"_parent,omitempty"`  // parent meta field
    Version        *int64                         `json:"_version,omitempty"` // version number, when Version is set to true in SearchService
    SeqNo          *int64                         `json:"_seq_no"`
    PrimaryTerm    *int64                         `json:"_primary_term"`
    Sort           []interface{}                  `json:"sort,omitempty"`            // sort information
    Highlight      SearchHitHighlight             `json:"highlight,omitempty"`       // highlighter information
    Source         json.RawMessage                `json:"_source,omitempty"`         // stored document source
    Fields         map[string]interface{}         `json:"fields,omitempty"`          // returned (stored) fields
    Explanation    *SearchExplanation             `json:"_explanation,omitempty"`    // explains how the score was computed
    MatchedQueries []string                       `json:"matched_queries,omitempty"` // matched queries
    InnerHits      map[string]*SearchHitInnerHits `json:"inner_hits,omitempty"`      // inner hits with ES >= 1.5.0
    Nested         *NestedHit                     `json:"_nested,omitempty"`         // for nested inner hits
    Shard          string                         `json:"_shard,omitempty"`          // used e.g. in Search Explain
    Node           string                         `json:"_node,omitempty"`           // used e.g. in Search Explain

    // HighlightFields
    // SortValues
    // MatchedFilters
}
```

Comment: Why the current solution doesn't satisfy you ? What output do you have ?

Comment: @aureliar the current solution does not actually add the ID anywhere. It prints the email and name fields, but leaves the ID field empty.

Comment: Isn't the name of `ID` in the resulting elasticsearch output `_id`? Then it should be `json:"_id"`. But that will not work, as _id is one level up to the rest of the data. Also, why are you marshalling it back to json? Isn't the ID already available on the `hit` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work like this:

```golang
var srs []StructuredResponse
for _, hit := range elasticsearch.Hits.Hits {
    var sr StructuredResponse
    if err := json.Unmarshal(hit.Source, &sr); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    sr.ID = hit.Id

    srs = append(srs, sr)
}
```

The ID is already available in the hit. See https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/82129300722c28a88207fd5dfed442668d9e264d/search.go#L749

Comment: Correct! This worked like a charm! If it's not too much to ask, as im still learning - could you please explain what i was doing wrong and what you did?

Comment: 1) you do not need to marshal the `hit.Source`. It is already marshalled as it is of type `json.RawMessage` (see `SearchHit` struct in your question). 2) there is no id in the source. It only contains `name` and `age`. The id is in the hit and that is already unmarshalled by olivere's package.

Comment: What I did: Unmarshal the `hit.Source` to a `StructuredResponse` variable (no ID in source) and after I take the `Id` from the `hit` and additionally write it to the struct variable.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense! I need to read more into slices, appending, & how marshal/unmarshal works, and when to use it. I missed the RawMessage part, but the appending part is a tad bit confusing. I really appreciate you! @Tehsphinx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fields of `elasticsearch.Hits.Hits` are exported, you shouldn't need to Marshal the output.

```
for _, hit := range elasticsearch.Hits.Hits {

    SR = append(SR, StructuredResponse{ID: hit.ID, Email: hit.Email, Name: Hit.Name})
}
```

This will give you an slice with a complete set of items (SR). At that point you should be able to Marshal that slice into JSON, if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Getting SR2 is not a type. Also, they are not exported.

Comment: Sorry I should have used `StructuredResponse` instead of SR2, updated the example.

Comment: ! That's starting to make sense! Thanks! My second concern is, would calling hit.email result in an error? since it is nested inside the struct. I've updated my question to also include the struct within Olivere's package

Comment: `hit.ID` is actually `hit.Id` and `hit.Email` and `hit.Name` do not exist. You have to unmarshal `hit.Source` to get them. See my answer.